# Compiling stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: compiling, texstudio

I'm using TeXstudio.

Today, I added a couple of lines to my paper, went to compile it, and now TeXstudio is stuck in an infinite loop, where there's just that constant blue circle rotating. Even when I close the document and open it up again, it's still compiling? I've even restarted my computer and opened up TeXstudio again, and it's still doing it.

There is one warning message; "old toc file detected, not used; run LaTeX again."

I'm not sure what this means? I've done some Googling and have been told to delete all toc files. When I go to delete it, it says "The action can't be completed because the file is open in pdflatex". I assume I can't delete it while TeXstudio is infinitely compiling? But how do I stop it compiling?

Comment: Pressing the escape button should abort compilation in TeXStudio. If that does not work, you can terminate the process using the Windows Task manager.

Comment: You could navigate to the folder that contains the tex file, and delete everything but your sources. In particular, delete any `.aux`, `.toc`, etc. files. If compiling still gets stuck, You need to identify the lines that broke the document and create a minimal working example that reproduces the error.